# How to deduplicate with group by in pig-latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a two-column data set, specifying some group name variable and users belong to it in long form.

```
A  user1
A  user3
B  user1
B  user3
C  user1
C  user2
```

Using pig-latin, I want to remove duplicates of groups that contains same members of user id, to get something like

```
A  user1
A  user3
C  user1
C  user2
```

I guess I need to group by the group name, and try to dedupe by the content of user ids, but I have no idea how to do it. Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: How do you know to remove group B vs group A?

Comment: It can be any of them.